# TextBox value based off dropdown

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I am still very new to using powerapps, but here goes:  i have a dropdown that has a list of choices that is pulling from a List-Choice column,  with options like A, B, C we will say.  based on the dropdown selected i would like to a corresponding text label to show the cost of said choice.  example:

```
dropdown choice        text label value
A                      $100.00
B                      $150.00
C                      $25.00
```

any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can use the [Switch function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-if) or the [If function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-if). For example, this could be the expression in the 'Text' property of your label:

```
Text(
    Switch(
        Dropdown1.Selected.Value,
        "A", 100,
        "B", 150,
        25),
    "$0.00")
```

Or using the [If function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-if):

```
Text(
    If(
        Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "A", 100,
        Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "B", 150,
        25),
    "$0.00")
```

Comment: Thank you so much